# Moving page numbers outside of page margins

Tags: margins, page-numbering

I am writing my dissertation in LaTeX, using the turabian formatting package. The dissertation handbook for my university include the following line: "All margins must be one inch wide. Page numbers should not fall within the one-inch margins."

I have one inch margins all around, but I cannot figure out how to move the page numbers so that they are not within the page margins. Any guidance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{turabian-thesis}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok, I think this will do:

\documentclass[12pt]{turabian-thesis}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-6]


\end{document}

The turabian-thesis class does margins exactly the way I want them, except for the page numbers bit.

Comment: Do not provide a MWE in a comment but as part of the original question.

Comment: @bopgah: Where can we get `turabian-thesis.cls` - your `\documentclass`?

Comment: It's from the turabian formatting package, available here: https://ctan.org/pkg/turabian-formatting?lang=en

Comment: @bopgah: Using [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry)'s `margin=1in` option sets the text block boundary with the page number in the *footer* and *header* necessarily outside this boundary. So, by default, your minimal example achieves the goal that you're after.

Comment: I guess it depends how you interpret "Page numbers should not fall within the one-inch margins." I was taking that to mean that the numbers should not be in the margins, but should be placed further into the page. But you seem to be taking it to mean the exact opposite. No idea who is right now.

Comment: To be absolutely sure, use the showframe option of geometry to show the actual boundaries (top of header, baseline of footer).

Comment: @bopgah: Earlier editions of Turabian's *A Manual for Writers* provide guidelines and examples with headers and footers not inside the margins themselves. More so, it is not uncommon that a department or university provides specific formatting instructions shared with these earlier editions.

Answer (score 1):

Having headers or footers (with page numbers) removed from the margins (in effect, having page numbers "not fall within the one-inch margins") can be accomplished by using the `includeheadfoot` option with the [`geometry`](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. This option places both headers and footers within the `\textheight` of each page.

To make this change, adjust the preamble to the following:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
```

Through this method, space for both a header and a footer is allocated within the `\textheight` of each page of the document.

It may be preferable, however, that space for a header or footer only be provided where needed on a page (e.g. space for a header only on pages with numbers located at the top of the page).

With the `turabian-thesis` document class, this would require pages that use the `plain` page style only reserve space for the footer and allow text to start immediately under the top margin. Likewise, pages that use the `headings` page style only reserve space for the header and not the footer. More so, the title page (using the `empty` page style with no header or footer) would have no space reserved for either a header or footer.

To implement this approach, make the following changes to your document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{turabian-thesis}

% Set geometry package defaults to match default layout, albeit with no binding offset
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in, ignoreall, onecolumn}
\makeatletter
    \geometry{headheight=\dimexpr \f@size pt \relax}
\makeatother
\geometry{footskip=0.5in}

% Make \headsep and \headheight adjustable where plain page style used
% New variables to adjust \headsep and \headheight
\newlength{\plainheadsep}
\newlength{\plainheadheight}
% Set new variables to initial defaults
\setlength{\plainheadsep}{\headsep}
\setlength{\plainheadheight}{\headheight}
% Append new variables to each instance in which plain page style used
\makeatletter
    \appto{\ps@plain}{%
        \setlength{\headsep}{\plainheadsep}
        \setlength{\headheight}{\plainheadheight}}
\makeatother

% Adjust page layout at specific instances in the document
% Title page has no header or footer included in \textheight
\preto{\maketitle}{%
    \newgeometry{margin=1in, ignoreall, noheadfoot}}
% After title page, footer included in \textheight
\appto{\maketitle}{%
    \newgeometry{margin=1in, ignoreall, includefoot}}

% With start of main matter, header included in \textheight
% Where plain page style used, header removed so footer is typeset above bottom margin
\appto{\mainmatter}{
    \setlength{\plainheadsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\plainheadheight}{0in}
    \newgeometry{margin=1in, ignoreall, includehead}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{MWE}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-6]

\end{document}
```

This approach is certainly more complex, but should have the desired result when using the `turabian-thesis` document class.